# Animation only glitches in mouse hover state of the DOM

Tags: jquery, css

On this site https://riskversity.com/

the menu jumps when hovered.   But it's proving difficult to troubleshoot because the inspector uses a mobile touch interface and the error is only happening on mouse hover state

Comment: See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212) — in short: no. I’m not going to click on your link. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a lot be we can't help you with your glitch unless until we see how you code your website.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media (min-width: 896px){
.menu-item.sfHover > .sub-menu, .menu-item:focus > .sub-menu, .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu {
    opacity: 1!important;
    margin-top: 0; // updating to this will may help you
    pointer-events: all;
}}
@media (min-width: 896px){
.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 18rem;
    z-index: 99;
    border-radius: .4rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: .618em .5em;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    display: block!important;
    opacity: 0!important;
    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in .35s; // updating to this will may help you
    transition: opacity ease-in .35s; // updating to this will may help you
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1.5rem rgb(20 30 40 / 5%);
}}
```

Comment: Updating with a commented line in your existing CSS may help you! :)